# Unity Fade delay when game ends

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm fairly new at Unity and i'm trying to making a game.
I want to have an subtitle fading in when you're at the end of the game. This start when you hit a button.
But when I code a image that I fadein, it plays it directly when you start the game.
Do you guys know a solution?

```
#pragma strict

private var guiShow : boolean = false;

var car : GameObject;
var rayLength = 10;
var guiObject : GUITexture;
var fadeTime = 1.0;
enum Fade {In, Out}
var fadesubtitles : boolean = false;


function Update ()
{
    var hit : RaycastHit;
    var fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, hit, rayLength))
    {
        if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "car")
        {
                guiShow = true;
                if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
                {
                    guiShow = false;
                }   

                else if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
                {
                    guiShow = false;
                }
        }               
    }
    else
    {
    guiShow = false;
    }
}




function OnGUI()
{
    if(guiShow == true)
    {
        GUI.Box(Rect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 150, 25), "Press F to escape");
         if(Input.GetKeyDown("f")){
                fadesubtitles = true;
             }
     }
}
if (fadesubtitles == true){
             yield FadeGUITexture(guiObject, fadeTime, Fade.In);
             yield WaitForSeconds(3.0);
             yield FadeGUITexture(guiObject, fadeTime, Fade.Out);
}

function FadeGUITexture (guiObject : GUITexture, timer : float, fadeType : Fade) {
     if (subtitles == true){
     var start = fadeType == Fade.In? 0.0 : 1.0;
     var end = fadeType == Fade.In? 1.0 : 0.0;
     var i = 0.0;
     var step = 1.0/timer;

       while (i < 1.0) {
         i += step * Time.deltaTime;
         guiObject.color.a = Mathf.Lerp(start, end, i)*.5;
         yield;
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the value is the same in the inspector? If you changed it then the default setting in code no longer matters because it is public.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start your game object in the 'disabled' state (uncheck it in the inspector).  Then at then end of the game, have some code that enables it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**iTween**](http://itween.pixelplacement.com/index.php).

```
FadeFrom(GameObject target, Hashtable args)
```

Example:

```
iTween.FadeFrom(gameObject, iTween.Hash("alpha", 0f, "amount", 1f, "time", 2f));
```